# Jquery, alert con cierre automático y redireccionar a otra pagina

Tags: jquery

¿Como puedo hacerlo utilizando jQuery? mostrar alert y redireccionar a otra pagina.

Eso de redireccionar con javascript lo hago, pero quiero hacerlo con jQuery ya que quiero agregarle un cierre automático al alert y tengo entendido que con js no es posible, lo que tengo es así:

```
<script> 
  alert("Guardado"); 
  window.location='Lista.php'; 
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485086/programmatically-close-alert-in-javascript
TL;DR: básicamente, un alert no lo puedes ocultar sin que tú hagas click en el botón

Comment: Busca en google modal jQuery y te sale un montón para elegir...

Comment: @TonyMuñoz Puedes crearte un dialog para esto y cerrarlo automáticamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para realizar lo que quieres puedes usar sweetalert, que te permite crear alertas con cierre automatico, acá te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$("#boton").on("click",function(){
  swal({
  title: 'Alerta con cierre automatico!',
  text: 'Esta alerta se cerrara en 2 segundos.',
  timer: 2000
}).then(
  function () {},
  // handling the promise rejection
  function (dismiss) {
    if (dismiss === 'timer') {
      console.log('La alerta fue cerrada en 2 segundos')
      //Aqui puedes hacer tu redireccion
      //location.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com";
    }
  }
)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.0.1/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.0.1/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="boton">Alerta</button>
```

Comment: como podría usarlo con un form y que el alert este en otra pagina?

Comment: Eso parece otra pregunta, crea una nueva pregunta y coloca lo que has intentado para ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: ya la publique amigo http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32547/form-submit-con-button-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Eso no es posible con el alert. [Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020830/autoclose-alert) hay una respuesta de stack que trata el mismo tema.

Con respecto a la redirección podés utilizar

```
window.location.href = "tupagina.com"
```

Eso es Javascript puro, porque en este caso Jquery la termina complicando. [Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-page-in-jquery) hay otro tema donde se toca este otro tópico.

Si aún así quieres hacerlo con Jquery te dejo el código:

```
var url = "http://tupagina.com";
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos!

Comment: El OP está preguntando por una solución con jQuery... y eso sí sería posible

Comment: exacto, como podría solucionar ese problema, con js lo hago sin cierre automático pero tengo entendido que con jQuery es posible

Comment: y el alert con cierre automático?

Comment: Ahi le agregué el código, igual no estoy de acuerdo con responder ciegamente sin recomendar soluciones mejores. Hay gente que consulta por determinada herramienta por el simple hecho de que no conoce otras. En este caso le di una mejor alternativa. Además yo nunca dije que no sería posible hacerlo con Jquery

Comment: Que yo sepa no es posible cerrar un alert, solo es posible simular el comportamiento con otros elementos. Te recomiendo ver el Modal de Bootstrap que seguro te va a encantar

Comment: claro amigo, eso de redireccionar con javascript lo hago pero quiero hacerlo con jQuery ya que quiero agregarle un cierre automático al alert y tengo entendido que con js no es posible, lo que tengo es así <script> alert("Guardado"); window.location='Lista.php'; </script>