# form Submit con button jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, eventos

tengo un formulario de dos paginas y quiero usar el evento del botón jQuery del pagina 1 en la pagina 2, para mostrar un mensaje jQuery:

Pagina 1 index

```
<form method="post" action="Guardar.html">
     <input type="submit" name="boton" id="boton"/>
</form>
```

Pagina 2 Guardar.html

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.0.1/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.0.1/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>   
<script>
$("#boton").submit()("click",function(){
    swal({
    title: 'Alerta con cierre automatico!',
    text: 'Esta alerta se cerrara en 2 segundos.',
    timer: 2000
}).then(
    function () { },// handling the promise rejection
    function (dismiss) {
        if (dismiss === 'timer') {
        console.log('La alerta fue cerrada en 2 segundos')
        location.href = 'index.html';
    }
    }
    )
})
</script>
```

Quiero llamar el botón de mi form a esa pagina con jQuery para hacerlo funcionar

Comment: No entiendo que quieres hacer, ¿quieres que al momento de dar click en submit, aparezca la alerta? o ¿quieres que aparezca en la pagina 2?

Comment: si que aparezca la alerta pero esta separada en dos paginas diferentes, integrada en una sola si puedo pero es un form que le llega a la otra pagina

Comment: Tienes una pagina `pagina1.php` donde tienes el formulario y haces post a `pagina2.php`, pero quieres que desde `pagina2.php` se detecte el evento `click` y se haga post del formulario??

Comment: si @sioesi exacto, solo quiero la funcionalidad del botón lo demás se como hacerlo quiero llamar al botón desde el formulario de la pagina1 a la pagina2

Comment: deberias en tu archivo `pagina1.php` poner `<?php include 'pagina2.php';?>` para poder acceder al elemento html y capturar el evento

Comment: no es con php @sioesi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, lo que quieres hacer no es lo mas prolijo, pero si quieres hacer que te funcione eso, cambia tu código de la pagina 2 por este:

```js
 $(document).ready(Alerta);

 function Alerta() {
   swal({
     title: 'Alerta con cierre automatico!',
     text: 'Esta alerta se cerrara en 2 segundos.',
     timer: 2000
   }).then(
     function() {}, // handling the promise rejection
     function(dismiss) {
       if (dismiss === 'timer') {
         console.log('La alerta fue cerrada en 2 segundos')
         location.href = 'index.html';
       }
     }
   )
 }
```

Comment: diste en el clavo, gracias soy nuevo en jQuery

Comment: Me alegro que te sirva, igual te comento que eso no es nada prolijo hacer eso, no es un reproche es solo un comentario. Saludos!